# Enable and disable a VPN-connection with one Shortcut (nm-applet)?

Tags: scripts, shortcut-keys, network-manager, vpn, button

Is this possible?
I want to have one Shortcut which works like a On/Off button for a VPN (similar to a wireless on/off Button on many laptops). To achieve this, I would probably need a script involving the network manager?

Reason: I have to connect and disconnect my VPN a lot. Every of these connects or disconnects takes three clicks, which adds up, plus my mouse is very insensitive (even in the most sensitive setting)

I have LM 18.1 Mate, with 4.8 Kernel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just found the solution, very straight forward.

Simply creating two shortcuts, with the commands below:

for VPN ON: nmcli con up servername

for VPN OFF: nmcli con down servername

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I turned my single shortcut into a toggle with a conditional command: `bash -c 'if [[ -n $(nmcli con show connection-name | grep "VPN connected") ]]; then nmcli con down connection-name; else nmcli con up connection-name; fi'`.

Answer (score 2):

I took this a bit further and thought I'd share it here.

I created a .sh script and an associated .desktop file so I can easily invoke this from Gnome.

The shell script I've placed in ~/.local/bin/vpn-toggle.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

CONNECTION_NAME=Home

if [[ -n $(nmcli connection show $CONNECTION_NAME | grep "VPN connected") ]]; then
  nmcli connection down $CONNECTION_NAME;
else
  nmcli connection up $CONNECTION_NAME;
fi
```

Remember to change the CONNECTION_NAME to the name of your connection.

The .desktop file I've placed in ~/.local/share/applications/vpn-toggle.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
#Icon=/path/to/icon/icon.svg
Name=VPN Toggle
Exec=/home/tons/.local/bin/vpn-toggle.sh
```

You need to fix the Exec path to match your system. I couldn't get it to work with ~ and didn't care to investigate further.

Comment: You could make it better by making `CONNECTION_NAME="$1"` and wrapping around `$CONNECTION_NAME` with double quotations. The first one makes the script generalized, so that a user can give the VPN name as the argument, and second one makes spaces inside VPN name acceptable.